# react-test-renderer's create() vs. @testing-library/react's render()

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I'm new to React and confused about all the testing libraries.  I got my test code to work but it seems redundant to have to call `create()` from react-test-renderer in order to use its `toMatchSnapshot()` and have to call `render()` from @testing-library/react in order to use its assertions such as `getByLabelText()`.

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import {act, create} from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders a login screen', () => {
    let mockInitialState: AppState = {
        auth: initialAuthState
    };

    let component = <Root initialState={mockInitialState}/>;

    let tree = null;
    act(() => {
        tree = create(component);
    });
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    const {getByLabelText, getByText} = render(component);
    expect(getByLabelText(/Email Address.*/));
    expect(getByLabelText(/Password*/));
    expect(getByText('Sign in'));
});
```

As a newbie, it's hard for me to understand the difference between all these React libraries.  But I'm thinking there must be a simpler way.

How can I simplify my test code so I only have to call one thing that renders the component so that I can do snapshot testing and more specific assertions?

Answer (score 15):

I got the answer from Ziad Saab at Codementor.io:

- `create()` allows you test against the virtual DOM (i.e. the "React DOM")
- `render()` comes from react testing library and renders your tree but also allows you to have all the get*() assertions.  It allows you to test against the DOM.

Here's how the code can be simplified:

```
it('renders a login screen', () => {
    let mockInitialState: AppState = {
        auth: initialAuthState
    };

    const {container, getByLabelText, getByText} = render(<Root initialState={mockInitialState}/>);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(getByLabelText(/Email Address.*/));
    expect(getByLabelText(/Password*/));
    expect(getByText('Sign in'));
});
```

Ziad let me know that there was no reason to have `act()`, it was something to work around a bug in `create()`.  Now that the code doesn't used `create()` there is no need for `act()`.

As a result, my snapshot now contains `class` instead of `className` because `class` is what's in the actual HTML DOM whereas `className` is its equivalent in React's "Virtual DOM".

(Before) Snapshot with `create()` based on React's Virtual DOM:

```
className="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-256"
```

(After) Snapshot with `render()` based on HTML DOM:

```
class="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-256"
```

Comment: is there any benefits of testing against DOM instead of Virtual DOM? like any particular situation where virtual DOM testing should be considered?

Comment: Generally I would prefer testing the virtual DOM and only test the actual DOM to validate some key requirement that the virtual DOM doesn't allow me to validate.  For example, I would write a test against the DOM if a customer reported a bug on a particular browser and I can't reproduce the bug with the virtual DOM.

Comment: I've noticed that DOM events, such as `onClick` are stripped out when rendering through HTML DOM? So it may be a good idea to use virtual DOM for snapshots?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Create React App then I'd stick with react-testing-library since it comes with it.

Instead of container, you can also use [asFragment](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#asfragment) for snapshot testing.

```
 const { asFragment } = render(<Root initialState={mockInitialState}/>);
 expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: `container` was never used and `asFragment` seems undefined. Did you mean to destructure `asFragment` rather than `container`? Also, what's the advantage of using `asFragment` over `container`? Thanks!